# difference between 'APPLICATION_JSON' and 'APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring development and want to know what is the difference between 
`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`?

I have a thought of both are representing same `application/json` content type but if I put `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` some compiler errors are shown to add `@controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations to my rest controller and When to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public @ResponseBody String sendInvite( ... ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To quote the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html), `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` is a "public constant media type for `application/json`", whereas `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` is a "String equivalent of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`".

Attributes on Java annotations can only be one of a limited set of types. This prevents `MediaType` from being used as an annotation attribute. To overcome this, a `String` is used instead along with the various `String` constants on `MediaType` including `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`.

Outside of an annotation, if you want to refer to a media type you should use the more strongly typed `MediaType` rather than passing around a `String` that may or may not actually be a media type. So, for example, you'd use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` rather than `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`.

Comment: from static block APPLICATION_JSON =valueOf(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);