# How to correctly generate Json without Backslashes

Tags: java, json

Problem:

I get json with backslashes as response from a GET Request

`@RequestMapping(value = "repuve/recibe_captcha", method = RequestMethod.GET,`
`produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

like this:

```
{"mensaje":"Proceso ejecutado correctamente.","folio":"1652989601959","resultado":"{\"idSalida\":1,\"descSalida\":\"Proceso Correcto\",\"data\":[.....]}"}
```

When expected Result is like this:

```
{"mensaje":"Proceso ejecutado correctamente.","folio":"1652989601959","resultado":"{"idSalida":1,"descSalida":"Proceso Correcto","data":[.....]}"}
```

(The data array has a b64 image).

This is how json is created:

```java
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
object.put("idSalida", 1);
object.put("descSalida", "Proceso Correcto");
jArray.put(captcha);
object.put("data", jArray);
```

I've tried some answers from StackOverflow using `replace()` but none of them seems to work for me.

Is there another way to remove the backslashes and get the correct json format delivered to front?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: That "expected Result" in the question is not valid JSON, if that is what you are expecting. You could make it valid by removing the 3rd double-quote, and surrounding the entire thing in `{ ` and `}`. What you show as the actual output you are currently  getting is not a valid Java `String` representation of a JSON object, either. Maybe there are some copy/paste problems in the question?

Comment: Also, are you using Spring? Do you want to receive a string representation of the JSON object (where double-quotes will be escaped) or an actual JSON object? See [difference between 'APPLICATION_JSON' and 'APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38614050/12567365)

Comment: I edited the question to show the exact output. Also String representation it is.

Comment: andrewJames is right – the output you currently expect is not valid JSON.

Comment: what does the  method declaration that the `@RequestMapping` annotation look like, i.e. what is the return value?

Comment: Also, I recommend you create a static class with the structure you want and use an ObjectMapper instead of building a JSONObject by hand

Comment: @andrewJames it wouldn't compile if they used `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: Actually, spring should already have an object mapper configured, so you should be able to either return that JSONObject or the static class I mentioned directly

Comment: ResponseEntity<Respuesta200>(srvRsp, HttpStatus.OK);

Where srvRsp = json.

The thing is thst i just need the \ removed. That's how front needs to catch to use it.

Comment: I guess i have to review all, since i can't explain it simply i don't understand it well enough. thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any JSON generating framework should actually escape the nested quotation marks. If you expect the string to look differently, you will have write code that assembles that JSONary string the way you want.